# How can I split a repository apart into smaller atomic repositories?

Tags: git

I've read "[Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)" but I'm not quite sure how to use this to achieve what I'm looking for. We currently have one large project that contains our schema/entities, our front-end web processes, and 2 versions of our REST API. I'd love to separate all of this into separate repositories if possible. Here's the kind of directory structure we have at the moment:

```
lib/Project/Entity/*.pm
lib/Projcet/Data/*.pm
lib/Project/Server/Controller/*.pm
lib/Project/Server/Controller/WS/1/*.pm
lib/Project/Server/Controller/WS/2/*.pm
lib/Project/Server/Form/*.pm
```

And so on. I'd like to be able to take the `Entity` and `Data` directories and move them to a new repository, and preferably move them as well:

```
lib/Project/Schema/Entity/*.pm
lib/Project/Schema/Data/*.pm
```

With the remaining files I'd like to split them apart into 2 more repositories, one for our front end server, and one for the REST API. I figure even though the REST API has 2 different versions we can split this into 2 separate branches (v1 and v2 branches).

I feel like filter-branch is pretty much exactly what I want (maybe with additional commits on top to move files), but I can't quite see exactly how to make this happen. Does anyone have any advice?

I should add that maybe `git rm --ignore-unmatch` might be what I want, but the file structure in HEAD at the moment is most certainly not what the structure was in older commits (this repository spans almost a decade of history). What I really want is "take commits that touch these files: `foo` but ignore all other commits. Sort of like a UNION of git log :)

Answer (score 2):

The git command you're looking for can be found in [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).  It is able to take an existing git tree and include only certain components from it.  Note that it **rewrites your git tree**.  So make sure you have a backup of the tree or copy it into a different directory and operate in the new directory.

For stuff in a subdirectory, note this part of the manual which describes how to do it well:

```
   To rewrite the repository to look as if foodir/ had been its project
   root, and discard all other history:

       git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
```

Comment: I don't think that's adequate. For example, I need lib/Data and lib/Entity to be as part of the same repository (and prefixed in the same manor) - from reading the manual pages of git-filter-branch, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @ocharles: Everything is possible. Look at the example index filter using `sed` in the manpage. (It's the very last one.)

Comment: Yeah, the example I quoted was the easy one.  You can do arbitrary filter expressions by passing it a script.

Comment: is it possible to rewrite the repository as if only foodir/ ever existed, but not set foodir/ as the tree root?

Comment: Yes, using --tree-filter I'm sure it's possible.  See the examples in git filter-branch --help and modify the command to remove everything but that directory.