# GIT clone one SVN project out of a multiproject structure

Tags: git, svn, clone, repository

We like to use GIT and we want to clone step by step projects out of SVN.

Our SVN structure looks like this:

```
thrunk/
-------/project1
-------/project2
-------/project3..N
branches
---/devlopment
-------/project1
-------/project2
-------/project3..N
---/feature-2
-------/project1
-------/project2
-------/project3..N
tags
---/v1.0
-------/project1
-------/project2
-------/project3..N
```

For example we like to clone only project2 first. How can we do this without loosing the entire history of branches and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach will be to use `git svn` to import the entire history into git, and then use [standard methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106073/how-can-i-split-a-repository-apart-into-smaller-atomic-repositories) with `git filter-branch` to split each subdirectory into its own git repository.

Comment: I've searched for the `git filter-branch` and found example.
First i clone ist normaly with `git svn clone REPO -s -A ./authors.txt` and then use `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch /project1 /project3" --prune-empty -- --all` is this correct

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your branch and tag history is tricky here because of your svn structure.

You can use [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) tool. 
In your case the command will be
svn2git /svn --trunk /trunk/project2 --tags /tags/ --branches /branches/

Comment: The command knows that I only needs  project2 in all branches and tags, because I  defined it in the `--trunk` parameter?